# Does "for" mean "as" in the sentence "Look what your mum had for a sister!"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "for" in the bold sentence? Is it an idiomatic use?

> He told Hagrid about the pale
>   boy in Madam Malkin's.
>   "--and he said people from Muggle families shouldn't even be allowed
>   in."
>   "Yer not from a Muggle family. If he'd known who yeh were -- he's grown
>   up knowin' yer name if his parents are wizardin' folk. You saw what
>   everyone in the Leaky Cauldron was like when they saw yeh. Anyway, what
>   does he know about it, some o' the best I ever saw were the only ones
>   with magic in 'em in a long line o' Muggles -- look at yer mum! **Look
>   what she had *fer* a sister**!"

Comment: Compare *He's weird! He has a spider for a pet!* Your cited text is a slangy construction that insultingly "objectifies" the mother's sister (in standard English, we use ***who*** to refer to people, not ***what***).

Comment: Yes, well, I am sure JK Rowling meant it if she wrote it! The speaker here is ***Hagridm the giant. So, his speech is uneducated and dialectal***. Yes, the idiom is: to have someone or something for. Look what he had for schoolbooks. Look what they had for a football pitch. Hagrid, being uneducated would use what instead of who.